# Unchecked cast warning when adding generic parameter

Tags: java, generics

The following Java code does NOT generate an unchecked cast warning (testing with Eclipse compiler for Java 8):

```
class Parent<T> {}

class Child<T> extends Parent<T> {}

class Test {
    <T> void test() {
        Parent<T> p = new Child<T>();
        // cast accepted by compiler:
        Child<T> cast = (Child<T>)p;
    }
}
```

So I understand the compiler must somehow have picked up that if `p` is both a `Parent<T>` (by compile-time type) and a `Child` (by run-time cast), then it is safe to assume it is a `Child<T>` as `Child`'s passes its type parameter in its `extends` clause.

However the following similar code DOES generate an unchecked cast warning:

```
class Parent<T> {}

class Child<T, U> extends Parent<T> {}

class Test {
    <T, U> void test() {
        Parent<T> p = new Child<T, U>();
        // cast considered unsafe by compiler:
        Child<T, ?> cast = (Child<T, ?>)p;
    }
}
```

Yet the reasoning for considering the first example safe should also apply here! If `p` is a `Parent<T>` and a `Child` then it should be a `Child<T, ?>`, given `Child`'s `extends` clause!

(Note that I do NOT include the `U` in the cast because that could indeed not checked, neither at compile-time or run-time.)

Is there any way to cast to a sub-type having additional parameters, without warnings?

Comment: Section 5.5.2 of the JLS seems to be related but I'm having trouble parsing the text. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.2

Comment: For me both examples compile without warnings. I'm using Oracles Java SDK 1.8.0_112's javac.

Comment: @TomHawtin a cast is absolutely necessary: even after erasure, compile-time type of `p` is `Parent`, which needs explicit casting to be converted to `Child`. The question is whether the cast should be considered "unchecked". @ValentinRuano Interesting, so that would be a bug of the Eclipse compiler. I'll make more experiments today and maybe submit a bug to them.

Answer (score 0):

As said in my comment those two cast work in Oracle's Java 1.8.0_112 compiler so presumably is a compiler error or limitation if you like.

I guess both cast should NOT be unsafe following the principle that assuming the Subclassing class is the correct one (i.e. the instance is indeed a `Child`) it must be true that it compatible with `Child<T, ?>` if it is a `Parent<T>`. In contrast it would not work (i.e. produce a warning) if you try to cast it to something like `Child<U, V>` where `U` is not guaranteed to be `T` or `V` is anything but `?`, because there are Child's that are `Parent<T>` that are not necessarily `Child<U, V>`.